# Transform into a const vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some vector of `Foo`s at hand and I want to transform it into a vector of `Bar`s, and a `const` one. The best way I can think of is:

```
Bar foo2bar(const Foo& foo);

std::vector<Foo> foos = {...};

const std::vector<Bar> bars = [&foos] {
    std::vector<Bar> bars;
    bars.reserve(foos.size());
    std::transform(foos.cbegin(), foos.cend(),
                   std::back_inserter(bars),
                   foo2bar);
    return bars;
}();
```

And I think the return value of the lambda should be elided by most compilers, so this should be close to ideal. The only disadvantage is probably the need to create a lambda, but I don't think it's too much of a problem.

Is there any insidious problem with this approach, and is there any better way (e.g., faster, cleaner)? C++11 is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your simplest solution is to drop the `const` requirement altogether. You can still expose a reference-to-`const` to other scopes.

Failing that, this should be fine. The lambda body will probably be inlined, "creation" of the lambda is a compile-time process, and the return value will either be moved or elided altogether. Your approach is quite elegant, actually.

Comment: Yeah, it's a style guideline of my team that objects should be marked `const` whenever possible (maybe a bit pedantic sometimes, but makes for super safe code), so I have to try to figure something out. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @ZizhengTai: Yep I advocate `const` wherever possible. But you have to know where to draw the line.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly cannot abide the idea of a lambda, then you could reach for boost's `transform_iterator`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

Bar foo2bar(const Foo& f) {
    return Bar {};
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> foos = {  };

    using boost::make_transform_iterator;
    const std::vector<Bar> bars (make_transform_iterator(foos.begin(), &foo2bar),
                                 make_transform_iterator(foos.end(), &foo2bar));
}
```

However, the lambda has no performance penalties after optimisation and is arguably less cryptic, so I would encourage that.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could move your `foo2bar()` function into your `Foo` class as a *conversion operator*:

```
struct Bar {};
struct Foo
{
    // conversion opertor
    operator Bar() const
    {
        // code to create Bar bar
        return bar;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> foos = {};

    const std::vector<Bar> bars(foos.begin(), foos.end());
}
```